# SQLAlchemy: Difference between session.commit() and session.execute('COMMIT')

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to understand the difference between `session.commit()` and `session.execute('COMMIT')` but I can't find anything in the documentation.

They seem to do different things, for example, this:

```
db.session.commit()
db.session.execute("VACUUM ANALYZE my_table;")
```

Throws the error: `VACUUM cannot run inside a transaction block`.

But this works fine:

```
db.session.execute("COMMIT")
db.session.execute("VACUUM ANALYZE my_table;")
```

I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.4.42.

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?  I think that might be part of the reason the second one works because it probably shouldn't.

Comment: SQLA does not (mostly) inspect raw SQL you execute, so your manual `COMMIT` ends the current transaction of the connection the session is using and SQLA will not start a new one, before the connection is returned to the pool.

Comment: @IljaEverilä one of the code blocks in [this section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_transaction.html#managing-transactions) says *will automatically begin again* is that only for "select" queries? *begin transactions automatically as needed* "as needed" = select?

Comment: In "will automatically begin again" you should not that the previous statement was `session.commit()`. There SQLA ends the transaction, commits, and returns the connection to the connection pool (that's the gist of it, I may have forgot the details). When you issue a new query using the session, SQLA gets a new connection from the pool and starts a new transaction.